# Call templated function arguments

Tags: c++

This is my event handling method:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <typename... Parameters>
class Event
{
    typedef void (*FnTemp) (Parameters... Params);
public:
    void AddCallback(FnTemp Function)
    {
        m_Callbacks.push_back(Function);
    }

    void Broadcast()
    {
        for (FnTemp Fn : m_Callbacks)
            Fn(Parameters...);
    }
public:
    virtual const char* GetName() = 0;
    bool operator==(Event& ev) { return ev.GetName() == GetName(); }
    inline std::vector<FnTemp> GetCallbacks() const { return m_Callbacks; }
public:
    std::vector<FnTemp> m_Callbacks;
};
```

Everything works except the line 17 (Fn(Parameters...)). How do I pass the Parameters thing into the function parameters?

EDIT: The solution:

```
void Broadcast(Parameters&&... params)
{
    for (FnTemp Fn : m_Callbacks)
        Fn(std::forward<Parameters>(params)...);
}
```

Comment: Parameters is a bunch of types, you need actual values. Shouldnt brroadcast take parameters as input and std::forware those to the clalbacks?

Comment: Ohhhhh I'm an idiot, well my brain exploded here. Thanks!

Comment: You can create an answer to your own question, rather than editing the answer into the question.

Comment: How? I'm kinda new to stack overflow...

Comment: In the "Your Answer" box below, write out a well-formatted answer explaining that in addition to the template typename you also need to pass a parameter to pass a value into whatever you are templating. [Template parameters and template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) may be a helpful link to use as is [Function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) (as is all of [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/))